# Google Optimizer - server-side/client side dilemma

Tags: google-website-optimizer

I'm hoping to test different versions of a form with Google Optimizer (Multivariate testing).  The form is in an ASP include, but what the server-side code will load before Google's JS does.  Any ideas about how to approach this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem.  The trouble is that Google's multivariate test is designed to allow you to test two or more snippets of HTML and the multivariate test itself is controlled via Javascript.

So I'm afraid the only way this will work is if you can specify the HTML for Google Optimizer to use for the two versions of the form.  This could be made to work with basic forms, but if the form itself is dynamically created in ASP due to some other application requirement then I don't think Google Optimizer will work so well for you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected.  For anyone else who may stumble onto this question in the future, I did find this: http://www.gwotricks.com/2009/05/server-side-dynamic-section-variations.html.  This link  doesn't really solve my problem, but it may solve someone else's.

Comment: Another thought -- you might try using Google Optimizer to create two different links on the page before the form.  That way the user is just taken to one of two versions of your form.

Answer (score 1):

I think this helps you

[Gwo Tricks](http://www.gwotricks.com/2009/05/server-side-dynamic-section-variations.html)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this is the same link I posted above last year (see first comment to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably out-topic, but I guess you should implement the Multivariate testing by yourself in the ASP.

In the simple case, It is quite simple to implement on top of your existing application, so maybe this can do the trick in your case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following.  Are you suggesting that I build my own multivariate testing system?

Comment: Yes. This is something that is achievable, provided there aren't too many variants to test. 

Depending on the complexity of the test to perform, I'd suggest using more than one analytics tags to identify the various trends the user follow (for example if your layout has 2 or 3 main variants). For more variants, the time-spent on page, and refining using funnel can probably do the trick although It's very dependant on your system :) On one of our websites, we built up the 49 AdSense channels to test the variants of the system on 7 Ad Banners because the Google Solution was not working for us.

Answer (score 0):

I've made progress on a similar problem.  Basically, we want to A/B test 2 different page layout headers. There are some structural differences (it's not just switching out the CSS). We also don't want to wait for Google to flip the coin to determine which variation the visitor should see; instead, we want to choose the variation server-side and avoid a page redirect.  I'm now using Google Analytics Content Experiments instead of the deprecated Google Website Optimizer.  I don't know whether it's completely working yet, but my code is here:

[Google Analytics Content Experiments A/B testing server-side code without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403778/google-analytics-content-experiments-a-b-testing-server-side-code-without-page-r)