# How to test Google Analytics Content Experiments without waiting a few hours?

Tags: google-analytics, google-website-optimizer

I'm trying to set up some Google Analytics Content Experiments as mentioned here:
[Google Analytics Content Experiments A/B testing server-side code without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403778/google-analytics-content-experiments-a-b-testing-server-side-code-without-page-r)

I haven't gotten it working quite yet, and I keep needing to tweak my code and try out different things.  Then I deploy to a testing server (to avoid [the localhost problem with GA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address)) and then use an online proxy website to visit the testing server (since my office [IP is filtered out of my GA account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251922/is-there-a-way-to-stop-google-analytics-counting-development-work-as-hits)).  But then I need to wait roughly 3 hours before I see whether GACE graphs any visits.

Is it true that Google Analytics Content Experiments graphs are updated on something like a 3 hour delay?

Is there a way to see results sooner (to make my iterative tweaking/testing less time-consuming)?

Answer (score 1):

The real-time feature (in beta) is very useful when it comes to testing this sort of thing.
Unfortunately it only supports page view. Events are not supported.

(you have to be admin on the account to see it)

http://analytics.blogspot.fr/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html

Comment: Events are now supported (2014. jan) and are indeed useful in this situation!