# Google Analytics "advanced segment" for "New Visitors IE7 and earlier" vs "New Visitors with any other browser"

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing

I am struggling to create 2 advanced segments in Google Analytics:

**I want to compare "New Visitors using Internet Explorer 7 or earlier" vs "New Visitors with any other browser".**

I'm running a [server-side A-B test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403778/google-analytics-content-experiments-a-b-testing-server-side-code-without-page-r) using a custom variable (with value "A" or "B" based on the variation used).

The reason both should filter to "new visitors" is because I'm most interested to monitor the success of my *signup* form.

The reason I want to compare IE6/7 versus modern browsers is because I fear that my signup form might perform very badly with IE6/7.  (In my testing of it personally, it seems fine, but I have reasons to suspect my attempt to approximate IE6/7 is imperfect.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two segment setups worked for me when I just tested them.

For Only IE6/7
[image]

For Everything but IE6/7
[image]

Comment: Something like this might be good. But I wonder if there is a way to say "version < 8" instead of specifying 6.0 and 7.0 in particular?  Also, for your 2nd one, it looks like it would accidentally exclude Chrome/Firefox/etc 6/7 too.

Comment: If Chrome/Firefox/etc. versions are exactly 6.0 or 7.0, then yes they will be excluded.  However, from my own data, Firefox versions are 13.0.1, 14.0.1, etc.; Chrome are 20.0.1132.57, 21.0.1180.60, 21.0.1180.79, etc.; and Safari are 534.55.3, 534.57.2, 7534.48.3, etc.  Meanwhile, IE versions are 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, and 10.0.